# How to fix grid when there are columns of different sizes?

Tags: css, html, grid

I have build a custom grid with the following below similar to what is found on [Creating Your Own CSS Grid System](http://j4n.co/blog/Creating-your-own-css-grid-system).

When I try to display four items in two rows as two columns in each (tablet-col-6), the first two items will be aligned properly, but the third item will be misaligned and the fourth item is on another row. It is mainly due to the fact that the columns have different heights for each column. Using Bootstrap's grid system is not an option.

How can I resolve this issue?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:before, 
.row:after {
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px; 
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
 .mobile-col-12 {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .tablet-col-6 {
  width: 50%;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
 .desktop-col-12 {
  width: 25%;
 }
}

.border  {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container outline">
<div class="row">
<div class="mobile-col-12 tablet-col-6 desktop-col-3 border">Compellingly expedite intermandated paradigms via out-of-the-box architectures. Enthusiastically transition vertical networks after multimedia based best practices. Completely predominate principle-centered.</div>
<div class="mobile-col-12 tablet-col-6 desktop-col-3 border">Enthusiastically benchmark cooperative information through proactive methods of empowerment. Completely syndicate alternative.</div>
<div class="mobile-col-12 tablet-col-6 desktop-col-3 border">Progressively recaptiualize quality convergence through extensive innovation. Uniquely utilize.</div>
<div class="mobile-col-12 tablet-col-6 desktop-col-3 border">Proactively pursue quality leadership skills with innovative processes. Quickly actualize dynamic.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Current output

[image: 4 grid items with errors]

Desired output

[image: 4 grid items with errors]

Comment: that article re grids based on floats is a little old. You might want to check out [this article](https://tutorialzine.com/2017/03/css-grid-vs-flexbox), and perhaps [this very well done video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc). Here's another [article worth reviewing](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/)

Comment: @gibberish i am going to convert it to use flexbox to see what happens, i will post an update soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things need to be fixed:

- The selectors in the the media queries are missing `.` e.g. replace `mobile-col-12` with `.mobile-col-12`
- Clear the floats on every first item of the row. And you must cancel the previous clearings within different breakpoints if needed.

Below is the updated part of media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  .mobile-col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tablet-col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .tablet-col-6:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    clear: both; /*clear floats*/
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .desktop-col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .desktop-col-3:nth-child(n) { {
    clear: none;  /*cancel clearing*/
  }
}
```

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyBJqb)**

Floats are outdated for creating layout, consider using Flexbox, CSS Grid instead.

Comment: good catch on the typo, i will be converting to flexbox and will try to provide an update when completed

Comment: Don't update your current question to flexbox, ask a new question if you need any help on that.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because it resolved my issue. I created another question for the flexbox help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955434/how-to-wrap-four-columns-into-two-rows-of-two-columns-with-flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simple experiment that adds flexbox-based equal-height columns to Bootstrap's grid system.

The row uses the custom `.row-eq-height` class defined in [this example's CSS](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css) to make all of its columns automatically be of equal height.

All of the columns will stretch vertically to occupy the same height as the tallest column , so the next one will be perfectly left aligned.

[image]

Comment: Clearly you didn't read this in the question: ***Using Bootstrap's grid system is not an option.***

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I did not notice... but also can be useful to someone :)

Comment: @Stickers I will be trying to convert this using flexbox and will provide an update soon, thanks for reading my question as i am trying to find an alternative to Bootstrap's grid system